# Probably a pointer issue but not sure why

Tags: c, bluetooth, arm, lpcxpresso

This is going to be a bit abstract due to the specific ARM (LPCXpresso 1115R/303) Cortex M0 and the H6 bluetooth module, and with NXP software there are a ton of driver files that are linked so hopefully the code snip below will be enough to identify the problem.

I am creating a simple menu system through bluetooth. Everything works with communcation. I send the message from the board, it is visible on the phone, I respond and print the value in the console of the program. All are exactly what I want them to be. But this is what happens:

1) start debug session and resume

2) 1st menu sends to phone, correct.

3) Type response to phone and send, correct.

4) message appears in console exactly as entered from phone (Just the number 1 appears)

5) Have if loop that checks to see if Buffer value == '1';

6) must not == 1 because it never enters the loop.

7) reprints the value of the buffer, and it still equals 1.

The only hint I have is a warning that says "makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]" on the assignment line as indicated below.

```
void ArmPeripheral() {
UARTCount = 0;
LPC_UART->IER = IER_THRE | IER_RLS; /* Disable RBR */
UARTSend( (uint8_t *)menu1, sizeof(menu1));
LPC_UART->IER = IER_THRE | IER_RLS | IER_RBR; /* Re-enable RBR */

while(1) {
if(UARTCount != 0){
    printf("%s 1st print\n",UARTBuffer);
    int bVal = UARTBuffer; // This is where the error occurs, tried uint8_t, did not work.
    printf("%s This is bVal\n",bVal);
    if(bVal == 1) {  //have tried 1, '1', and "1" none work
        printf("inside loop %s...\n",UARTBuffer);
        printf("%s This is bVal\n",bVal);
        LEDControl();
    }
    printf("%s second print\n",UARTBuffer);
    UARTCount = 0;
}
}
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRhbA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it was just a simple pointer issue. UARTBuffer is a external volatile uint8_t in the UART.c file, and even though it is not defined as a pointer, it is pointing to a buffer somehow.

```
int bVal = *UARTBuffer;
if(bVal == '1') {
```

The above worked, but if anyone has any more in depth information that could explain why I would be interested in knowing. This is how I initialized the buffer:

```
extern volatile uint32_t UARTCount;
extern volatile uint8_t UARTBuffer[BUFSIZE];
```

Comment: Your code says that `UARTBuffer` is an *array* of `uint8_t`s. Do you understand how arrays work in C?

Comment: You try to print an int value with %s in your printf. You need %d for an int.